# How make seo friedly url in subdomain

Tags: php, .htaccess, seo

I have a website say `' www.example.com'` , I have also created sub domain in this site, say `'www.alpha.example.com'`. I need to convert a dynamic page into SEO friendly URL. 
My URL is `'www.alpha.example.com/test/article.php?cat=people'`

Into

`'www.alpha.example.com/test/article/people'`

How to solve this using `.htacces`

Please help me.

Comment: What do you currently have for you .htaccess file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it this way for completeness. This way if they enter `www.alpha.example.com/test/article.php?cat=people` then it will redirect to 
`www.alpha.example.com/test/article/people` also so you will be covered both ways.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?alpha\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /test/article\.php\?cat=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule .* /test/article/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?alpha\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^test/article/([^/]+)/?$ /test/article.php?cat=$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside `DocumentRoot` of `www.alpha.example.com` create a file called `.htaccess` with this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?alpha\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^test/article/([^/]+)/?$ test/article.php?cat=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```